# Adding boost header files gives compile time errors

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2017, c++14

When i add the header file

```
  #include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
```

It gives couple of errors

```
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::type_of::id2type_impl' is not a specialization of a class template
error C2059: syntax error: '<'
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

which point towards the line number 125 in typeof_impl.hpp file.

Comment: What version of C++ are you compiling against?

Comment: @NathanOliver  The version is c++14 .

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: for local files use "myfile/file.cpp" but it should be header ....

Comment: What version of boost are you using? Does it support Visual Studio 2017? I ask because from time to time I see people here using 5 year old versions of boost.

Comment: @drescherjm  the boost version is boost_1_64_0

Comment: That version of boost may be too old. It was not listed as a primary compiler here: https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_64_0.html although it is in the additional test compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading  drescherjm , sehe's comments i changed some settings in the visual studio and when i changed platform Toolset from visual studio 2017 v(141) to visual studio 2015 v(140) , the program compiled sucessfully.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what file you mean:

```
custom/boost_1_72_0/boost/typeof/typeof_impl.hpp
custom/boost_1_72_0/boost/typeof/msvc/typeof_impl.hpp
custom/boost_1_72_0/boost/typeof/dmc/typeof_impl.hpp
```

If you mean `msvc/typeof_impl.hpp` then most likely you have a preprocessor issue (where the source is mutated due to a redefined preprocessor token).

If there's no such file than @drescherjm's comment may be on point: there might be specific MSVC support missing in that version you're using.

Comment: the file is "custom/boost_1_72_0/boost/typeof/msvc/typeof_impl.hpp"